# Proving that $\{ a^i b^j c^{\max(i,j)} \}$ is not context-free

Tags: context-free, pumping-lemma

> Prove that $L$ is not a Context-free language, where
> $$L = \{ a^{i} b^{j}c^{h}\mid i,j,h\in \mathbb{N} \wedge h = \max(i,j)\}.$$

I have an idea: It can be divided into two situations:

1. When $i < j$, $w = a^{i} b^{j} c^{i}$
2. When $i > j$, $w = a^{i} b^{j} c^{j}$

Then with the help of the pumping lemma，but I will only use special examples to prove it. I always feel not rigorous. How should I write it more rigorously?

My writing is:

When $i < j$, $w = a^{i}b^{j} c^{i}$, $i = 4$, $j = 3$. $w = aaaa bbb cccc$, then use $uvxyz$ to prove step by step.

Comment: *How should I write it more rigorously?* Try to emulate known examples: ones that you've seen in class, ones that you've seen in textbooks, or ones that you've seen on [cs.se].

Comment: Just don't use specific values. For example, my process is to let i=4 and j=3. But I don’t think this is rigorous.

Comment: providing a counter-example to a statement **is rigorous**